# Function to filter excel table data in to a new dataset based on value defined in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables of data, the first is **EmployeeSalaryTbl** which holds the salaries for employees over time:

[image: Salary Info]

and the second **StaffDetailsTbl** which has details on the employee discipline etc.

[image: Staff Details]

I use various columns from the tables in a function to calculate total employee salaries per month and I'd like to re-purpose the function to only calculate the salaries dependent on a specified discipline in a given cell, for example **Progamming**.

To do this, I was thinking, is it possible to filter the results of EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee], EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary Start Date], EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date] etc to only contain the rows where the employee has the **Programming** discipline through a lookup in to the **StaffDetailsTbl**?

Comment: So what is the desired output here. Maybe you'r only interested in the latest update per employee?

Comment: The function I have includes the functionality to extract the latest employee Salary. I'm looking to get all results associated with all employees with a specific discipline to then feed it in to the function I have.

Comment: So something along the lines of `=SUM(FILTER(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary],(COUNTIFS(StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],EmployeeSalaryTbl[Employee],StaffDetailsTbl[Discipline],"Programming"))*(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date]="")))` perhaps?

Comment: excluding the `*(EmployeeSalaryTbl[Salary End Date]="")` bit gives me the full list which is what I'm after thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesnt need to be pretty and you just want to sum the totals
You could put this in the column next to your table, starting at the first row you want to check from. then at the bottom sum up the values. You can change where it says programming to make it a cell reference if you want to check for various disciplines

`=IF(INDEX(StaffDetailsTbl[Discipline],MATCH(EmployeeSalaryTbl[[#This Row],[Employee]],StaffDetailsTbl[Employee],0))="programming",EmployeeSalaryTbl[[#This Row],[Salary]],"")`